# How to navigate using navigation menu in angular js routing on visualforce page salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, bootstrap

I am using navigation menu in angularjs. I am unable to navigate to partial html pages. How can i achieve the same.
How can i navigate to specific vf page.
My folder structure is as follows;

AngularApp.resource(Resource Name)
 --app
   app.js
   --controllers
       ---
       ---
       ---
   --directives
      ---
      ---
   --services
      ---
      ---
   --views
     createWorkOrder.html 
     workOrderGrid.html

src
    classes
      ---WorkOrderControllerExtension.cls
    pages
      ---WorkOrderVF.page

Here is my code.
VF Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="WorkOrderControllerExtension"  docType="html-5.0"
 sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Stylesheet, 'main.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Stylesheet, 'Images/sprite-workorder.png')}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- ng-table css -->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Stylesheet, 'ng-table.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'angular.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'angular-route.min.js')}"/>

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'angular-resource.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js')}"/>
    <base href="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp, 'app/')}" /> 
    <!-- Include ngTable js file-->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/directives/ngTable.js')}"/>   

    <!-- Include all individual files as needed for AngularApp-->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/app.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/controllers/workOrderController.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/controllers/searchWOController.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/controllers/caseController.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/controllers/navController.js')}"/>

    <!-- <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp,'app/services/workOrderSVC.js')}"/> -->


    <!-- Visualforce Remote Objects. -->    
    <apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="CaseModels">
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Case" jsShorthand="case" fields="Id,CaseNumber"/>
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="WorkOrderModels">
        <apex:remoteObjectModel jsShorthand="wo" name="Work_Order__c" fields="Id,Name,Case__c,City__c,Street__c,Zip__c"/>
    </apex:remoteObjects>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navPanel" >
          <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="navController">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">        
              <div class="woSpriteImage woHeadTitle"></div>
              <div class="appHeading">WORK ORDER APP</div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">              
              <li class="createWO"><a href="/">CREATE WORK ORDER </a></li>
              <li class="workOrdList"><a href="#/getWorkOrder">WORK ORDER LIST</a></li>
              <li class="caseList"><a href="">CASE LIST</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div ng-app="workOrderApp"  class="container form" width="100%">            
        <ng-view></ng-view>         
    </div>



</apex:page>
```

**App.js(Routing)**

```
 var app = angular.module('workOrderApp',['ngTable','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) 
{
        $routeProvider
            // route for the home page by default
            .when('/', {                
                templateUrl : 'views/createWorkOrder.html',
                controller  : 'woFormController'
            })
            // route for the work order grid page.
            .when('/getWorkOrder', {
                templateUrl : 'views/workOrderGrid.html',
                controller  : 'searchWOController'
            })
            // route for the work order view page.
            .when('/getWorkOrder/:woId', {
                templateUrl : 'views/createWorkOrder.html',
                controller  : 'woFormController'
            })
            // route for the work order grid page.
            .when('/getCaseList', {
                templateUrl : 'views/caseGrid.html',
                controller  : 'caseController'
            }) 
            // route for the work order view page.
            .when('/getCaseWorkOrder/:caseId', {
                templateUrl : 'views/caseWorkOrderGrid.html',
                controller  : 'searchWOController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
}]);
```

**navController.js(Controller)**

```
    app.controller('navController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    //Get Case Id form query string.
    var csId = getWoUrlParameter('RecordId');
    var wId = null;


    $scope.getWoURL = function(wId,csId){     
         if(wId != "null" && csId != "null")
         {
            return  "https://" + $window.location.host + "/apex/WorkOrderVF?"+"RecordId="+csId+"#/getWorkOrder/"+wId;

         }
         else
         {
            return  "https://" + $window.location.host + "/apex/WorkOrderVF?"+"#/getWorkOrder/";
         }     

  };    



    //Format proper url and return query string value.
    function getWoUrlParameter(param, dummyPath) {
        var sPageURL = dummyPath || window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split(/[&||?]/),
            res;

        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i += 1) {
            var paramName = sURLVariables[i],
                sParameterName = (paramName || '').split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === param) {
                res = sParameterName[1];
            }
        }

        return res;
    }





}]);
```

Please help.

Comment: Navigation in Angular is normally within a **single** page where any href value is a relative URL. Moving to a new Visualforce page will result in a new instance of the Angular app being created which is probably not what you want. This https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub is an example of an Angular app running in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes. i want to navigate to different .html pages via navigation menu. How can i configure the route to start after /apex/WorkOrderVF?. Now it is taking my resource file path as my html files and js files are stored there.

Comment: OK, the .html is a different thing to a Visualforce page. If you are storing your .html partials as static resources this https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub/blob/master/metadata/staticresources/github_app_js.resource illustrates one way to access them.

Comment: @Keith: I have my navigation menus on VF page. Based on menus and their parameters i want to redirect user to different .html pages which are in static resource. Is there an issue with my routing code?

Comment: The href would normally be e.g. `<a href="#/getWorkOrder"/>` to match your second route.

Comment: Ejaz, as a moderator I've cleaned up some of the comments here. Having too many confuses people and makes it harder to follow your question. Please do not provide new information in comments but apply it as updates to your question.

Comment: If your question is not receiving enough attention please consider that it may be too little question, too much code or that it may be off-topic to the side and that we lack enough people with the specific knowledge (bootstrap, angular) or that you are not using the correct tags to attract people with the rights skills. There's nothing in your question that indicates that the issue you're having is specifically related to salesforce.  Please clean up your question to be more on-point or you may risk it being closed as too broad too.

Comment: ok @Samuel...i will repost the question thanx.

Comment: Hello All, I have resolved the issue by myself taking the other approach of redirection by calling a function on navigation menus. Thanx a lot.